# Unable to change file/folder Permissions (Tried Root Explorer Pro, ES File Explorer)

Tags: android, file, permissions, root, file-permissions

I am attempting to change permissions for the folder which is inside Data folder in Internal Storage.
My Device is Unlocked and Flashed with a firmware & with Super SU for root.

Using Root Explorer (Pro), I allowed Root access. I also went to root of System partition and mounted it to RW.

However when I try to change the permissions of a file or folder inside internal storage or even SD Card, I get the following error.
**"Permissions change was not successful. Please note that some file systems do not allow permission changes."**

Explored for a while with different file managers. Here's what I tried and observed.
In these steps I am using ES File Explorer.

- Open ES File Explorer -> Select Root Explorer -> Tap on it again -> Select Mount R/W -> Select All.
- Navigate to a folder -> Select any file/Folder -> Select Properties -> Has 3 properties displayed -> Readable, Writeable, Hidden -> Next to them there is an option to edit (Available only for some folders).

I next checked for which folders these options are available. Here is what I observed.

1. Inside SD Card or Internal Storage, **options to edit are NOT available** . Checked multiple folders within them.
2. I immediately navigate to /storage, and check the folder "emulated". **These options ARE available**.
3. Within /storage, I check the folder which contains my sd card items. **These options are NOT available**.
4. I then navigate inside /storage, and check folder "0", **these options are NOT available**.

What is the issue? How can I change the permissions for that folder?

Comment: I resolved this myself. I was looking at the wrong folder. at the wrong path.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the permission of file in your internal storage then just open root explorer (I assume it already rooted) and navigate to

> /data/media/0/(yourfolder)/(yourfile)

Long press and change the permission... Voilà!

This is basically due to some of them having Fat32 Filesystem format while they are in storage/sdcard which are different than Linux/UNIX file system permissions!
So if you go through `/data/media/0/` then it's in ext3/ext4 format which is why you can change the permissions!!

For more info go through this..
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/help/unable-to-change-file-permission-rooted-t2038107

Comment: Thanks for the /data/media/0/ tip!